# Event trigger not working on RichEditBox XAML-C# windows 8

Tags: c#, event-handling, winrt-xaml

I am using RichEditBox with XAML and C#
I have following 3 events in XAML and corresponding handlers in C#(back code)

```
DoubleTapped="RichEditBox_DoubleTapped" RightTapped="RichEditBox_RightTapped" PointerReleased="RichEditBox_PointerReleased"
```

But after putting debug points, I found, none of them is getting triggered.

DoubleTapped event gets triggered if I double tap not on the word but on empty space within the RichEditBox. Once this event is handled, double tap starts working even on words.

I need to handle any of the above events on words. But none of them is responding as expected.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: I do have:
`IsHoldingEnabled="True" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" IsRightTapEnabled="True"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okies. Got other 2 events working as:

```
SelectionChanged="RichEditBox_SelectionChanged" Holding="RichEditBox_Holding"
```

Above events mentioned in the question might be a bug, not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

this is a user control and I've got this code XAML:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="TextElementControl" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=userControlModified}" ManipulationMode="None" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                    AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    SizeChanged="TextElementControlSizeChanged"  
                    IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" DoubleTapped="TextElementControl_DoubleTapped" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Padding="10,10,10,10"/>
```

in the code behind :

```
private void TextElementControl_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //log message, breakpoint is hitting this during double click.
        }
```

on some portion of the code we've set

```
void ControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {  
    TextElementControl.IsReadOnly = false;
}
```

it works and I hope it helps you.